# External oscillator problem

Tags: pic, c, oscillator

I have this sample program to blink LED with PIC18F4550 using external oscillator.

I'm using a 20.000 MHz crystal oscillator with 30pF capacitors.

The problem is **when I wire the capacitors the the ground the LED doesn't blink (still off), but when I disconnect them from ground (not wired) the LED starts blinking**. Blink speed change with `_XTAL_FREQ`.

Program works well with internal oscillator (just by setting `FOSC = INTOSCIO_EC`)

*Is there direction wiring of capacitor or oscillator?*

**Ground here is PIC Vss**

This is when using PICKIT2 directly. When using the circuit alone like the scheme, nothing happens with `FOSC = INTOSCIO_EC` configuration (not working), but works well with internal oscillator.

[image: Schematic/Pinout]

```
#include<p18f4550.h>
#include "delays.h"

/* COMPILER DIRECTIVES FOR CHIP CONFIGURATION BITS*/

#pragma config FOSC = HS //INTOSCIO_EC    /* Sets the oscillator mode to HS */
#pragma config WDT = OFF   /* Turns the watchdog timer off */
#pragma config LVP = OFF   /* Turns low voltage programming off */
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF /* Compiles without extra debug code */

#define _XTAL_FREQ   12000000  //delay_ms change by changing this


void main(void) {
    TRISD = 0xF0; // PORT B Setting: Set all the pins in port B to Output.
    while (1) {

        LATDbits.LATD0 = 1; // RD-0 to High
        LATDbits.LATD1 = 1; // RD-1 to High

        __delay_ms(50); // Half sec delay

        LATDbits.LATD0 = 0; // RD-0 to LOW
        LATDbits.LATD1 = 0; // RD-1 to LOW

        __delay_ms(50); // Half sec delay
    }
}
/* THE END */
```

[image: Breadboard Setup]

Comment: 16 or 20 MHz crystal? 30pF or 22pF? There seems to be a contradiction. Also a layout view would help. Fairly certain it's a layout problem grounding the caps.

Comment: @Andyaka yes it 20MH I edited it sorry, what kind of layout problem ,I dont understand, I the caps wired to PIC ground (vss)

Comment: Circuit board? Bread-board?

Comment: it's breadboard

Comment: Picture would help.

Comment: 30pF is a lot for 20MHz crystal. Also ensure the capacitors are directly between pins 12-13 and 12-14 (vertically on the breadboard, not through the blue supply strip) and the crystal is also directly in the same hole quintuplets as pins 13 and 14

Comment: @Andyaka this is my picture scheme

Comment: @venny I added picture, the capacitors here are far from pins as u see, you mean I should stuck them to the pins??

Comment: Even if Andy's answer doesn't ultimately solve your problem, it's definitely part of the problem. It's very clear from your photo that the xtal is way too far from the chip.

Comment: Yes. You can move the PIC to have 4 holes for each pin. Then attach the components with no extension wires. It is better to solder the crystal with the capacitors to a 3-pin header and slide it in as one component.

Comment: Also the second power pins are unconnected. In most cases it will do nothing, but it might cause strange instability problems.

Comment: @venny for the first answer, without capacitor is works well, but with capacitor not working?? I mean I just put the xtal on pins 13,14 and it start to work, but when adding capacitor and wiring them to ground, the led stop working

Comment: Breadboards have a frequency limit of 10MHZ so it shouldn't work

Comment: I'm missing something. This device supports mixed internal-external oscillator mode, and you're just blinking a light, not using the USB module. Why not use `INTIO` mode and be done with it? You wouldn't need a crystal at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the picture tells the big story - it's a layout problem - the xtal needs to be mounted right up at the pic pins and the two capacitors need to connect to 0V via the shortest possible route. At the moment, the wires to the xtal and caps has too much inductance and not surprising this will not work correctly.

Comment: it' not working fine fine, but at least it blink in some way, thanks

Comment: just for your answer, without capacitor is works well, but with capacitor not working?? I mean I just put the xtal on pins 13,14 and it start to work, but when adding capacitor and wiring them to ground, the led stop working

Comment: That is probably due to parasitic capacitive coupling. If it does not work with capacitors attached, try lower value like 22, 18 or 15 pF. Sometimes 1Mohm across the crystal helps to start oscillation.

Comment: Are you sure the capacitors are the correct value and not 22nF instead of 22pF?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case Andy's answer doesn't solve the problem, here's something else I see. You've got _XTAL_FREQ set to 12MHz with a 20MHz crystal.

Plus, your delay functions are delaying for 50ms, not 500ms like your comment indicates. With the mismatched _XTAL_FREQ value and the mis-typed delay time, the actual delay will be (12/20)*50ms = 30ms.

That's 33Hz. The human eye may not be able to tell it's blinking at that rate.

Answer (score 2):

Try these configuration bits:

```
#pragma config PLLDIV   = 5         /* PICs 96 MHz PLL prescaler divided 
                                       by 5 for 20MHz input */
#pragma config CPUDIV   = OSC1_PLL2 /* System clock post scaler 
                                       [OSC1/OSC2 Src: /1][96MHz PLL Src: /2] */
#pragma config FOSC     = HSPLL_HS  /* HS oscillator, PLL enabled */
```

You will end up having clock frequency of  96/2MHZ = 48MHz which will produce instruction frequency of 12MHz which is the maximum for PIC18F4550.

Also PIC18F4550 datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf on page 27 recommends using 15pF capacitors for 20MHz crystal.

Looking at your picture I'm pretty sure you have a small typo in there. 2 of oscillators wires are connected wrong way
[image: 2 black wires should be swapped]

Answer (score 1):

after ensuring that your hardware connections are fine as pointed out, the other error must have been your capacitors value. I had exactly the same error where the MCU would blink the LED without the capacitors but turned off immediately after plugging the capacitors. The capacitors value I used were "223pF" instead of "22pF". Ceramic capacitors value are always in picofarads and therefore you have to  do the correct calculations. "223 = 22000pf"  while "0.022nF = 0.022x1000pF = 22pF." hope it helped you.